# Is $\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^{\mathsf T} (X^{\mathsf T}X)^{-1}x_i = p$ where $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am wondering if the following is equivalent:
$$\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^{\mathsf T} (X^{\mathsf T}X)^{-1}x_i = p$$
where
$$x_i \in \mathbb{R}^p$$ and $$X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$$

This further assumes that $X^{\mathsf T}X$ is invertible, and $x_i$ is a column vector corresponding to the $i$-th row of $X$.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\tr}{\mathrm{trace}}$I think you mean $x_i$ is the $i$-th *row* of $X$ (written as a column vector). Then yes, it is true. Consider the matrix $H:= X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$. The $i$-th diagonal entry of this is $e_i^T H e_i = e_i^T X(X^TX)^{-1}X^Te_i = x_i^T (X^TX)^{-1} x_i$, where $e_i$ is the $i$-th standard basis vector of $\Bbb{R}^p$.

Hence your sum is the sum of diagonal elements of $H$, which is $$\begin{align*}\tr(H)&=\tr\left(X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\right)\\ &=\tr\left((X^TX)^{-1}X^TX\right)\\ &=\tr(I_{p\times p})\\ &=p.\end{align*}$$

Comment: Note: I used the [cyclic property of trace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561012/prove-that-operatornametraceabc-operatornametracebca-operatornam) near the end.

Comment: You're right. I just changed the OP. Will study your answer right now in detail.

Comment: How did you get the second equality?

Comment: Seems like the trace of the product of matrices is equivalent to a permutation of the matrix products as long as the size conforms?

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed your comment.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that your problem is posed correctly. Notice that $(X^TX)^{-1}\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$, so it cannot even multiply $x_i$. However, this is fixed if you instead consider $(XX^T)^{-1}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, assuming it exists, which requires $p\geq n$. Assuming this, we can rewrite as follows:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^T(XX^T)^{-1}x_i = \sum_{i=1}^ne_i^TX^T(XX^T)^{-1}Xe_i,
$$
where $e_i$ is the $i$-th canonical basis vector. Denote $Y = X^T(XX^T)^{-1}X$, then we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^T(XX^T)^{-1}x_i = \sum_{i=1}^ne_i^TYe_i = \mathrm{tr}(Y).
$$
So your problem reduces to computing $\mathrm{tr}(X^T(XX^T)^{-1}X)$. By the cyclic invariance of the trace, we have
$$
\mathrm{tr}(X^T(XX^T)^{-1}X) = \mathrm{tr}((XX^T)^{-1}XX^T) = \mathrm{tr}(I_{n\times n}) = n,
$$
again recalling that $n\leq p$ since $XX^T$ exists.